# Why do I receive notifications and missed calls only when I open the chat apps on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, notifications

My iPhone 6s plus is connected to Wi-Fi but I only receive notifications when I open an app (WhatsApp, Messenger, viber, FaceTime and iMessage). Actually I receive e-mail notifications and I surf on Safari, that's it.

When I turned on the LTE I received notifications and when I turned off and then on the same problem happened. So I tried with Wi-Fi, turned it on and then off many times to get worked. I reset and erase all the settings. I also flashed my iDevice and updated the new iOS beta 5 13.4 and it doesn’t work. I changed my Apple ID. Same problem.

Comment: What are your notification settings? Are you using silent switch or Do Not Disturb?

Comment: Hi @Narjisse Is the phone in low power mode ?

Comment: @ankii no it is not

Comment: @Nic No iam not using what you said ! i already flah my idevise and my phone it is new

Comment: @NarjisseZei Go to Settings > General > background app refresh and enable all

Comment: @ankii i did but it doesn't work too

Comment: beta software isn't expected to work normally. It should be reported to apple. Also, you shouldnt use beta unless you're testing or developing it.